# List of JSON strings as command arguments

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, sh, gitlab, json

I've been working with GitLab CI recently to automate some busy tasks, namely auto releasing binaries for version tags.

For those who don't know Gitlab CI, it is very straightforward. It pulls the specified docker image and runs 'scripts' commands in the default shell of that docker container.

The release CLI docker image that Gitlab provides contains just the barebones, which means no bash, just sh (or something similar, I'm not exactly sure what)

I originally had this: *(extra job config removed for readability)*

```yaml
Release:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - |
      release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"${FILE_A_NAME}\",\"url\":\"${COMMON_URL}/${SPECIFIC_PART_A}\"}" \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"${FILE_B_NAME}\",\"url\":\"${COMMON_URL}/${SPECIFIC_PART_B}\"}" \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"${FILE_C_NAME}\",\"url\":\"${COMMON_URL}/${SPECIFIC_PART_C}\"}" \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"${FILE_D_NAME}\",\"url\":\"${COMMON_URL}/${SPECIFIC_PART_D}\"}" \
```

I am trying to make a CI template to reduce the number of times I copy this across multiple projects, allowing them to always use the latest CI config.
This can be done in gitlab using the `include:` yaml section.

But, Ive run into issues with creating an argument string to append to the end of the command.
Here is what I currently have:

```yaml
variables: # Example BUILD_ENVS
  BUILD_ENVS: "env_A env_B env_C"

Release:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - |
      ASSET_LIST=""
      for ENV in ${BUILD_ENVS}
      do
          ASSET_LIST="${ASSET_LIST} --assets-link \"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"common_name-${VAR}.bin\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"${COMMON_URL}/${VAR}/binary.bin\\\"}\""
      done
    - release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG $ASSET_LIST
```

When I echo this `ASSET_LIST` variable, I get the correct string. (*Both output the expected string*)

```bsh
echo $ASSET_STRING
echo "$ASSET_STRING"
```

But the `release-cli ... $ASSET_LIST` fails with this error:

```bsh
$ release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG $ASSET_LIST

time="2021-04-24T23:36:04Z" level=info msg="Creating Release..." cli=release-cli command=create name="Release v1.2.3" project-id=25750732 ref=3b5c58a057fd4ae781e7ce9e695dd8e5d88ffbf6 server-url="https://gitlab.com" tag-name=v1.2.3 version=0.7.0

time="2021-04-24T23:36:04Z" level=fatal msg="new CreateReleaseRequest: failed to parse assets: invalid JSON: \"\\\"{\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"File-A-binery.bin\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"https://url-to-file-A/binary.bin\\\\\\\"}\\\"\"" cli=release-cli version=0.7.0
```

---

What I've tried:

1. I've tried avoiding the problem altogether by creating a release and then adding each asset link through another API call. This didn't work due to Gitlab's Job token access rights (darn).
2. I've tried using single quotes to capture most of the string, but double quote escapes for variable replacement:

```bsh
ASSET_LIST=\'"${ASSET_LIST}"' --assets-link "{"name":"common_name-'"${VAR}"'.bin","url":"'"${COMMON_URL}"'/'"${VAR}"'/binary.bin"}"'\'
```

3. I've tried using `exec`:

```bsh
exec release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG $ASSET_LIST
```

4. Various other small syntax changes, but none of them have gotten me anywhere.

---

Unfortunately, I havent found a syntax/configuration that works.

I know that variables and variable expansion have some weird quirks, I just cant figure out how to make this work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution. It may not be the best way to do it. But it does work.

@ilkkachu had exactly what I needed in his answer on
[How can we run a command stored in a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/436496).

He listed a number of methods, but the one that worked for me was to the method of using the `$@` positional arguments.

Here is what I did:

```yaml
variables: # Example BUILD_ENVS
  BUILD_ENVS: "env_A env_B env_C"

Release:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - |
      for ENV in ${BUILD_ENVS}
      do
          set -- "$@" --assets-link "{\"name\":\"common_name-${VAR}.bin\",\"url\":\"${COMMON_URL}/${VAR}/binary.bin\"}"
      done
    - release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --tag-name $CI_COMMIT_TAG "$@"
```

While the plain shell that the docker image uses doesnt support arrays, It does have the positional argument array for scripting. Since we aren't running a script, but rather just a list of commands, we arent using the positional arguments and we can override the object and use it ourself.

For more information on why and how this works, refer to [@ilkkachu much longer/better answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/436496)

TLDR:
If you arent worried about having positional arguments in a script or command, use `set -- "$@" -arguement "{\"json\":\"part\"}"`
and `command "$@"` to easily create and use a list of arguments for a command.